# row-wise sum of boolean arrays in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, broadcast

Given the dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.array([True, False, True, False]),np.array([True, True, False, False])]})

                        A
0  [True, False, True, False]

1  [True, True, False, False]
```

How can I get the row-wise sum of the integer version of the boolean? for example:

```
cmd(A) = [2, 1, 1, 0]
```

What command can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way (probably faster without all the conversions to dataframe and lists):

```
(df.A.values+0).sum(0)
#[2 1 1 0]
```

The `+0` is to convert boolean to int and the sum is along axis 0 (row-wise).

Comment: Both Answers are good, thanks. I accepted this one because it seems faster.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
pd.DataFrame(df.A.tolist()).sum().tolist()
[2, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: It worked Thanks, but can you please explain it. I cannot understand why when you transform the dataframe to list and then back to dataframe it works

Comment: @lalalandla this is so called `'explode'` in row